# Finding values of same time every week. code provided, data provided. 4D-matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have coded this partly..but am not sure, since what i get is only partial data.
so i have a matrix 4D, it has dimensions: xV(6,24,63,15) ---> meaning: xV(min,hour,day,customer).. the data is collected every 10 min for 63 days for 15 customer.
so that is why first 6 row is 10 min interval.

what i want is that i can collect the data for lets say monday every week and use it for plot.
meaning there is 63/7 = 9 mondays.. 9 mondays having 24 hours where each hour has 6 data(every 10 min). i want for each of those hour each monday each 10 min a new matrix..so i can take the mean of it and plot..

is this possible?

i have come so far..but no luck:

```
n = 0;
m = 0;
while(n<24)
n = n + 1;
    while(m<6)
    m = m + 1;
    Va(:,m) = x(m,n,1:63,1); %(min,hour,day,line)
    Vb(:,m) = x(m,n,1:63,1);
    Vc(:,m) = x(m,n,1:63,1);
    end

end
```

the file: [xV.mat](http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/12402/xV.mat)

thanks again for help

Comment: What size would the matrix be, for each Monday? 6x24x15? Or do you want to combine those three dimensions somehow?

Comment: yes, cause the mean of the days has been taken, so there remains no days. only minxhourxcustomer..

Answer (score 0):

```
firstMonday = 1; %// index of first Monday. 1 if first day is a Monday
result = xV(:,:,firstMonday:7:end,:);
```

This gives a 6x24x9x15 matrix containing only Mondays. To average over all Mondays, use

```
squeeze(mean(result,3)) %// mean along 3rd dim. Size is 6x24x15
```

Comment: but when i wanna plot 1 customers all monday using this: plot(bb(1:6,1:24,1)) i get more than 6 graphs on the plot. but when i put 1 instead of 1:6 then it works. any way to make it plot it all for 1 customer? or what if i wanna plot 2 customers data so there is like 12 graphs..why does the error says it has to be 2D